# efficient symmertic computation in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

A common construct I've seen in algorithms that contain symmetry is

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n ; j++) {
        [compute x]
        objects[i][j] += x;
        objects[j][i] -= x;
    }
}
```

that (while still having O(n^2) complexity) reduces the amount of calculations needed by exploiting the symmetry. Could you tell me what's the way to introduce such an optimization in a pyspark code?

For example, I've written code that computes the force per unit of mass acting on each particle in a system per the formula (where `r` is the position):

```
         N    m_j*(r_i - r_j)
F = -G * Σ   -----------------
        i!=j   |r_i - r_j|^3
```

In it I first do a cross product of my dataframe with itself to get every pairwise interaction, and then aggregate them all by id to get the total force acting on each particle:

```
def calc_F(df_clust, G=1):

    # cartesian product of the dataframe with itself
    renameCols = [f"`{col}` as `{col}_other`" for col in df_clust.columns]
    df_cart = df_clust.crossJoin(df_clust.selectExpr(renameCols))
    df_clust_cartesian = df_cart.filter("id != id_other")

    df_F_cartesian = df_clust_cartesian.selectExpr("id", "id_other", "m_other",
                                                   "`x` - `x_other` as `diff(x)`",
                                                   "`y` - `y_other` as `diff(y)`",
                                                   "`z` - `z_other` as `diff(z)`"
                                                   )
    df_F_cartesian = df_F_cartesian.selectExpr("id", "id_other",
                                               "`diff(x)` * `m_other` as `num(x)`",
                                               "`diff(y)` * `m_other` as `num(y)`",
                                               "`diff(z)` * `m_other` as `num(z)`",
                                               "sqrt(`diff(x)` * `diff(x)` + `diff(y)`"
                                               "* `diff(y)` + `diff(z)` * `diff(z)`) as `denom`",
                                               )
    df_F_cartesian = df_F_cartesian.selectExpr("id", "id_other",
                                               "`num(x)` / pow(`denom`, 3) as `Fx`",
                                               "`num(y)` / pow(`denom`, 3) as `Fy`",
                                               "`num(z)` / pow(`denom`, 3) as `Fz`",
                                               )
    # squish back to inital particles
    sumCols = ["Fx", "Fy", "Fz"]
    df_agg = df_F_cartesian.groupBy("id").sum(*sumCols)
    renameCols = [f"`sum({col})` as `{col}`" for col in sumCols]
    df_F = df_agg.selectExpr("id", *renameCols)

    df_F = df_F.selectExpr("id",
                           f"`Fx` * {-G} as Fx",
                           f"`Fy` * {-G} as Fy",
                           f"`Fz` * {-G} as Fz")

    return df_F
```

But I know that the force between two particles is symmetrical - `F_ij = -F_ji` (I am assuming all masses to be equal) - so here I am computing a number of forces twice, instead of reusing them. So in this particular case I'd want to turn `df_clust_cartesian = df_cart.filter("id != id_other")` into `df_clust_cartesian = df_cart.filter("id < id_other")` for example, and somehow reuse these forces when computing the total force in the second part of the function. (Of course ideally I want to learn to do it in general)

Example input for this case would be

```
a = sc.parallelize([
    [0.48593906,-0.52435857,-0.53198230,0.46153894,-0.33775792E-01,-0.32276499,0.15625001E-04,1],
    [-0.65960690E-01,0.80844238E-01,-0.27603051,-0.57578009,1.1078150,-0.29340765,0.15625001E-04,2],
    [-0.34809157E-01,0.76795481E-01,-0.39087987,-0.55399138,-0.17386098,0.59250806E-01,0.15625001E-04,3]
])                                                           

from pyspark.sql.types import * 
 
clust_input = StructType([ 
    StructField('x',  DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('y',  DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('z',  DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('vx', DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('vy', DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('vz', DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('m',  DoubleType(), False), 
    StructField('id', IntegerType(), False) 
])    

df_clust = a.toDF(schema=clust_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to only compute your formula when `id < other_id`, and use that result to generate by symmetry all the elements for which `id > other_id`.

You would simply need to modify your filter by this

```py
df_clust_cartesian = df_cart.filter("id < id_other")
```

Then, once you have the dataframe `df_F_cartesian` you have one line per `(id, id_other)` pair. You can use that line to generate the line  corresponding to`(id_other, id)` and add a minus sign to `Fx, Fy` and `Fz`.

This could be done by adding the following step right before the aggregation:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sumCols = ["Fx", "Fy", "Fz"]
oppositeSums = [ (-F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in sumCols]
df_F_cartesian = df_F_cartesian.select(F.explode(F.array(
    F.struct(F.col("id"), *sumCols),
    F.struct(F.col("id_other").alias("id"), *oppositeSums)
)).alias("s")).select("s.*")
```

Comment: I tried this approach, and unfortunately it's almost 4 times slower than the original; maybe I'll try some different way to generate the symmetric data

Comment: So the goal was to optimize the job. In spark dividing the amount of computation by two is not really a big deal (but that was what the question was about), what really matters is shuffle and the way data is partitionned. How many distinct ids do you have, how any executors/cores and how much time does your job take?

Comment: Yeah I am beginning to think that maybe dividing the computation by 2 won't actually make it noticeably faster. I have 64000 ids. When running locally on 8 threads cpu + default parallelism of 16 it takes about 5min. When running remotely on 17 executors 2 cores each + default parallelism 64, it takes about a minute. And then I'd need to repeat it thousands of times (the algorithm itself is very inefficient tbh)